# Opening a door to another dimension (Kaluza-Klein like model)

Tags: general-relativity, metric-tensor, spacetime-dimensions, models, kaluza-klein

I start the subject with a small fantasy tale:  You walk in a forest, until you find a door standing on the ground.  You open the door, which let you enter a large room.  You are surprised since that room isn't shown behind the standing door.

I'm trying to show that this is theoretically possible in General Relativity by adding a simple circular dimension, like what is done in standard Kaluza-Klein theory (the "fifth dimension" is the "large room").  I don't consider wormholes, which need some exotic form of matter (negative energy density).  For simplicity, I consider spacetime to be flat everywhere, except in the "fifth dimension" around the door.  So consider the following 5D metric (I use units such that $c \equiv 1$ and metric signature $\eta = (1, -1, -1, -1)$):
$$\tag{1}
ds^2 = \eta_{ab} \, dx^a \, dx^b - D^2(x) \, d\theta^2,
$$
where $\theta$ is the circular coordinate in the fifth dimension and $D(x)$ is an arbitrary function of the 4D cartesian coordinates $x^a$.  Computing the components of the Riemann tensor is easy, using the vierbein formalism:
$$\tag{2}
R^5_{\;ab5} = \frac{1}{D} \, \partial_a \, \partial_b \, D,
$$
while $R^c_{\; dab} = 0$.  The Einstein tensor is easy to compute:
\begin{align}
G_{00} &= \frac{1}{D} \, \nabla^2 D, \tag{3} \\[2ex]
G_{0i} &= \frac{1}{D} \, \partial_i \, \dot{D} \tag{4} \\[2ex]
G_{ij} &= \frac{1}{D} \, \partial_i \, \partial_j \, D + \frac{1}{D} \, \square \, D \, \delta_{ij}, \tag{5} \\[2ex]
G_{55} &= 0. \tag{6}
\end{align}
Einstein FE gives $G_{AB} = -\, \kappa \, T_{AB}$, where $\kappa = 8 \pi G$.  This implies the components $T_{55} = 0$ and $T_{a5} = 0$.

Now, the question is to find a function $D(x)$ (lets call it "the door") which is almost $0$ everywhere (no fifth dimension in the 3D world), except inside a relatively small region of 3D space (the "door") where the function is large (so you could enter the door) and let you enter the fifth dimension (the "large room").  That function should give a stress-energy-momentum tensor that satisfies the *null* and the *weak* energy condition: $T_{ab} \, u^a \, u^b \ge 0$ for any null or light-like four-vector.  The door could depend on time (so it grows very fast, before shrinking to $0$ after a while), or stay static.

So is it possible to find such a "door" (i.e a function $D(x)$ that satisfies the conditions above)?

Is there another (simpler?) way to define a door to "an inner closed space", in General Relativity, without wormholes (which are using weird exotic matter)?

Comment: This sounds like Wheeler's bag of gold geometry.

Comment: What is $T_{\mu\nu}$ in this case? Since we are three dimensional beings, I would argue that 4 dimensions should suffice to create the large room (spatio-temporal)